# AWS SSM CreateDocument operation: Parameter "InstanceId" is not declared

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

I am learning AWS and while creating a SSM document i'm  not getting `IntanceID` while trying to create a `SSM Document`, I am using below `aws cli` and `yaml` to get the same.

**SSM Coommnad:**

```
aws ssm create-document --name "SSM Document-test" --content file://installtest.yml --document-type "test" --document-format YAML --region us-east-1
```

Below is [yaml](/questions/tagged/yaml)

```
description: Installs Docker on the Instance and tag it properly
schemaVersion: '0.3'
parameters:
  instanceId:
    type: String
    description: "Instance ID of an instance to install Docker to"
  build:
    type: String
    description: "The build of docker to install"
    default: "get" # default version
mainSteps:
  - name: AssertRunning
    action: aws:assertAwsResourceProperty
    isCritical: true
    onFailure: step:abort
    nextStep: installPackages
    inputs:
      Service: ec2
      Api: DescribeInstnaces
      InstanceIds:
        - "{{InstanceId}}"
      PropertySelctor: ".$Reservation[0].Instances[0],State.Name"
      DesiredValues:
        - running
```

Inspiration from [re-invent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaI2xkW85yE)

any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding another answer to make it clear. You can create Command or Automation based on your needs.

Refer [SSM Document schema](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/document-schemas-features.html)

** **Working Example for**  **Automation:****

cli : `aws ssm create-document --name "SSM-Document-test" --content file://SSM-Document-Test.yaml --document-type "Automation" --document-format YAML --region us-east-1`

```
description: Installs Docker on the Instance and tag it properly
schemaVersion: '0.3'
parameters:
  InstanceId:
    type: String
    description: "Instance ID of an instance to install Docker to"
  build:
    type: String
    description: "The build of docker to install"
    default: "get" # default version
mainSteps:
  - name: AssertRunning
    action: aws:assertAwsResourceProperty
    isCritical: true
    onFailure: Abort
    inputs:
      Service: ec2
      Api: DescribeInstances
      InstanceIds:
        - "{{ InstanceId }}"
      PropertySelector: "$.Reservation[0].Instances[0].State.Name"
      DesiredValues:
        - running
  - name: installPackages
    action: aws:runCommand
    inputs:
      DocumentName: SSM-Document-Test
      InstanceIds:
        - "{{ InstanceId }}"
      Parameters:
        build:
          - "{{ build }}"
  - name: createTags
    action: aws:createTags
    maxAttempts: 2
    timeoutSeconds: 60
    onFailure: Abort
    inputs:
     ResourceType: EC2
     ResourceIds:
     - "{{ InstanceId }}"
     Tags:
     - Key: docker-installed
       Value: TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks @Mahesh for the working example +1 already, this works. However, when i am trying to add `tags`  via    `action: aws:createTags`  it again throws same error, `CreateDocument operation: Parameter "InstanceIds" is not declared.`.

Comment: Added `createTags` step. I was able to create the document. Here is my partial output

`{
    "DocumentDescription": {
        "Hash": "945fb01d9f7f647b373f42548b25ee2e5e5d762d8e12097cef3d285416c0eaa2",
        "HashType": "Sha256",
        "Name": "SSM-Document-test",
        "Owner": "12987948928492849",
        "CreatedDate": "2022-07-11T09:44:45.678000-04:00",
        "Status": "Creating",
        "DocumentVersion": "1",
        "Description": "Installs Docker on the Instance and tag it properly",`

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 typos. `Api: DescribeInstnaces` and `PropertySelctor: ".$Reservation[0].Instances[0],State.Name"`.

Try this:

```
description: Installs Docker on the Instance and tag it properly
schemaVersion: '0.3'
parameters:
  instanceId:
    type: String
    description: "Instance ID of an instance to install Docker to"
  build:
    type: String
    description: "The build of docker to install"
    default: "get" # default version
mainSteps:
  - name: AssertRunning
    action: aws:assertAwsResourceProperty
    isCritical: true
    onFailure: step:abort
    nextStep: installPackages
    inputs:
      Service: ec2
      Api: DescribeInstances
      InstanceIds:
        - "{{ InstanceId }}"
      PropertySelector: "$.Reservation[0].Instances[0].State.Name"
      DesiredValues:
        - running
```

Comment: @ Mahesh.. thanks for the direction however, i still can see the error `An error occurred (InvalidDocumentContent) when calling the CreateDocument operation: Parameter "InstanceId" is not declared.`

Comment: My bad. There's another typo here - PropertySelector: `"$.Reservation[0].Instances[0],State.Name"`  (notice comma)
`PropertySelector: "$.Reservation[0].Instances[0].State.Name"`

Also dint notice create document command. Document type should be command

`aws ssm create-document --name "SSM-Document-test" --content file://installtest.yml --document-type "Command" --document-format YAML --region us-east-1`

Comment: This is what i get when using `Command`, `An error occurred (InvalidDocumentSchemaVersion) when calling the CreateDocument operation: 0.3 is not a valid schema version for Command document type`   It should be `Automation` only.

Comment: It's weird that document-type Command is erroring out. Try Automation

`aws ssm create-document --name "SSM-Document-test" --content file://installtest.yml --document-type "Automation" --document-format YAML --region us-east-1`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-actions.html

Comment: This what i tried which is getting the mentioned error.

Comment: Let me actually try to create it in my account. I'll get back with a working example.